# Qt 4.8.7 - Cross compilation error - symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _ZN7QWidget8qwsEventEP8QWSEvent

Tags: 16.04, qt, ubuntu-mate, raspberrypi, cross-compilation

I have cross compiled executable file from **QT 4.8.7** and i am running it on **Raspberry PI(Ubuntu OS installed in it)** which have installed QT 4.8.7 and **QT declarative module** also. When i run the cross compiled executable file (which is cross compiled on Ubuntu 16.04) on my raspberry pi, i got the error message like : **"undefined symbol: _ZN7QWidget8qwsEventEP8QWSEvent"**. I don't know why i am getting this error as both the side installed QT version is same and **arm-linux-gcc toolchain** is same.Qt Declarative module version is also same from both side. please help.